# How do i know which preprocessing was used for the model?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am at the moment trying to train a classifier using R with the `caret` library.

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10 , savePred=T, classProb=T, verboseIter = T, search = "random" )
start = proc.time()
start
mod <- train(x = data$data, y = data$labels, method = "svmPoly", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = "pca")
end = proc.time()
```

At the end of this my model should be stored in `mod`, but how do I know which parameter combination provided the best result, specifically regarding preprocess.

the only information I receive regarding pre-processing is

```
Pre-processing: principal component signal extraction (256), centered (256), scaled (256)
```

But doesn't state out of how many?

And is possible using the `search = random` method to retrieve more information, rather than the 3 plot values I received as output being.

```
  degree  scale        C           Accuracy  Kappa    
  2       0.108317686   0.9567723  0.70400   0.6711111
  3       0.004150808   0.5572215  0.67975   0.6441667
  3       0.616741666  64.7776012  0.74825   0.7202778
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are asking, but here is some info

- right now, `preProcess` does the same processing on all of the predictors so seeing `centered (256)` means that you had 256 numeric predictors and they were all centered. The exception to this is when you have non-numeric predictors and you should see an entry for `ignored`. Also note that 256 may be larger than the number of columns in your data if you generate dummy variables via the formula interface.
- Soon you will be able to tell `train` which predictors should be pre-processed (and in potentially different ways)

Max